# What is the point of testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

i got a little into testing, but i still dont know why should i do it in my apps.
lets say i have this class

```
class Human

  attr_accessor :age

  def initialize
    @age = 0
  end
end
```

and this test

```
describe Human do
  kid = Human.new
  kid.age.should == 0
end
```

the test passed, everybodys happy. But what did we really accomplish? This is of course very simple example, but it expresses what i mean. what informations test like this can provide me with?

Comment: The more you test the more apparent its value becomes.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, the code is so trivial that the test is far more trouble than it's worth. If you will write very simple applications (nothing wrong with that if it gets the job done), then so be it.

Most of the time in the real world though, you need to write tests for several reasons:

- To confirm for yourself the code works as you expect.
- To help isolate where a bug happened. You can look at the tests to see which components along the call chain have been tested thoroughly to then find the one that wasn't (for the case at hand). This helps you reproduce the error and isolate its cause.
- To allow for automation. Once written, the tests can be run by a continuous integration server forever. This way you know that some change you made down the road didn't break stuff that used to work.
- Documentation. When people join your project, or when you need to remember why you did what you did months ago, it is a lot better to look at code rather than lots of documentation text that is boring to read and probably not current. The tests show how the components are supposed to work and interact.
- Sometimes when I want to write some code I am actually not sure how it should look and what the API should be. Writing a test *first* helps me *flush* out that API and figure out what I need to do.

Of course tests need to be cheap to write so they can be thrown away as the functionality evolves. They also need to be fast to run, and there is a ton of literature on how to do that. A lot of teams are bad at testing, so it becomes so cumbersome they stop doing it. If you get good at it though, which isn't hard, testing is very powerful.

Hope that helps.

Comment: If you get into TDD, testing will also shape the way you code and the kind of code you write.

Comment: I actually just added a similar point before I saw your comment haha. Thanks for the excellent point.